# A shell script to ssh, watch log file, and run command

Tags: ssh, shell-scripting

I want a shell script that connects to a server via ssh, starts watching a log, and then touches a file. It's important that I do them in that order, because I want to see in the log the effects of the second command. How do I write this? If I try something like:

```
ssh myserver tail -f /some/path/logfile &
ssh myserver touch /some/path/another-file
fg  # hoping to see the output of first command
```

I get error about "no job control in this shell".

Answer (score 1):

The answer that @aviv-lo provided should work.

But few things that may fix your current method

- Add `set -m` for job control
- You *might* be also seeing an issue with your `ssh` client session is failing because it tries to use stdin.

Add `-n` to the backgrounded `tail` command.  For good measure maybe also  can add `-T`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -m
ssh -Tn myserver tail -f /var/log/messages &
ssh mysrever logger blah blah 
fg
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might be able to do is that you create the shell script locally as it's like on the server and pipe it to the ssh client

```sh
cat shell_script.sh | ssh syntax_to_connect_to_the_server
```